# External js file only loading on initial website visit, fails to load on refresh -- only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

having a bit of a backwards issue. I have a conditional script that loads when the website first loads, but when I refresh, it fails to load. I am seriously confused here, because all of my issues usually happen the other way. Here's my JS at the start of my `index.html` file. Note that I am using this hack I found on Stackoverflow to detect versions of IE specifically because the file I am trying to load, if it loads at all it will cause the entire site to break on IE instead of just parts of it not showing up. The script is for Google's Polymer `platform.js` if that makes any difference!

```
    <script>
        function detectIE() {
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
            var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

            if (msie > 0) {
                // IE 10 or older => return version number
                return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
            }

            if (trident > 0) {
                // IE 11 (or newer) => return version number
                var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
                return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
            }

            // other browser
            return false;
        }

        console.log(detectIE());

        if (detectIE() >= 1 && detectIE() <= 10) {
            console.log('this is below ie10');

        } else {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.src = '/bower_components/platform/platform.js';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    </script>
```

Basically the `platform.js` script has to load first before any other scripts or else anything done with the Polymer platform will not load. To this end I appended it to the head tag at the start `[0]`. Note that this script has been working fine for 4 months now, and just recently broke for no apparent reason in the last 2 days. I have determined that the script that detects for IE has no effect on the issue.

I really have no idea why it would load only on the FIRST time but fail to load on a refresh. Seriously at a loss here. I suspect something to do with Chrome's caching methods but I am not sure. It loads every time on Firefox/Safari/Opera/IE11.

Any direction/help would be appreciated. Thanks!